# Prove $\sin \alpha+\sin \beta+\sin \gamma \geq\sin 2\alpha+\sin 2\beta+\sin 2\gamma $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Prove that $\sin \alpha+\sin \beta+\sin \gamma \geq\sin 2\alpha+\sin 2\beta+\sin 2\gamma $ where $\alpha$ $,\beta$ $,\gamma$ are the angles of a triangle

Comment: The problem comes from the KöMaL magazine: http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=B4549&l=en It seems we have a cheater who asks illegal help for solving the contest problems of KöMaL.

Comment: @G.Kós Same story. Students never think about math but cheating. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use
$$\sin{2A}+\sin{2B}=2\sin{C}\cos{(A-B)}\le 2\sin{C}$$
$$\sin{2B}+\sin{2C}\le 2\sin{A},$$
$$\sin{2C}+\sin{2A}\le 2\sin{B}$$

Comment: Is it 2sinCcos(A-B)??

Answer (score 2):

$\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=\dfrac{a+b+c}{2R}=\dfrac{S}{rR}$

$\sin 2A+\sin 2B+\sin 2C=2(\sin A\cos A+\sin B\cos B+\sin C\cos C)$
$=\dfrac{a\cos A+b\cos B+c\cos C}{R}=\dfrac{2S}{R^{2}}$

$\sin A+\sin B+\sin C\geq \sin 2A+\sin 2B+\sin 2C$
$\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{S}{rR}\geq \dfrac{2S}{R^{2}}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $R\geq 2r$ : **Euler formula**

Comment: I proved your strange area formula! $(ABC)=\frac R2(a\cos A+b\cos B+c\cos C)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-geometric way.

Let $f(x,y,z)=\sum_{cyc}\sin x-\sin2x$. We want to minimize $f$ subject to the constraints $g(x,y,z)=x+y+z(=\pi)$, $\pi>x,y,z>0$. The method of Lagrange multipliers, $f_{*}=\lambda g_{*}$, gives the system of cyclic equations
$$4\cos^2x-\cos x+\lambda-3=0$$
with cyclic solutions
$$\cos x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{16\lambda-31}}{2}.$$
Since we have 2 possibilities for each of 3 variables, 2 of them must be equal at an extremum. Therefore the interior angles are $x,x,\pi-x$ at an extremum. Then the given inequality becomes
$$2\sin x\geq\sin2x-\sin4x$$
which is
$$\cos3x\geq-1.$$
The equality occurs when $x=y=z=\frac\pi 3.$