# Sinusoidal Inequality

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$, prove that $\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)+\sin(\gamma) \ge \sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta)+\sin(2\gamma)$.

Please note that all the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are acute.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\sin \alpha+\sin \beta+\sin \gamma \geq\sin 2\alpha+\sin 2\beta+\sin 2\gamma $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397910/prove-sin-alpha-sin-beta-sin-gamma-geq-sin-2-alpha-sin-2-beta-sin-2-ga). Really, the first port of call when you have a question like that would _not_ be to post it here, but to search if someone has already posted the same or a similar question. [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/) can also come handy.